# JavaScript ineritance. How is it working in the sample code shown?

Tags: javascript, function, inheritance, constructor, prototype

The following link is having the example code that I have shown here(comments are mine).

[2ality](http://www.2ality.com/2012/01/js-inheritance-by-example.html)

The code snippet:

```
function Point(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

function ColorPoint(x, y, color) {
    Point.call(this, x, y);
    this.color = color;
}

function inherits(SubC, SuperC) {
    var subProto = Object.create(SuperC.prototype);
    // At the very least, we keep the "constructor" property
    // At most, we preserve additions that have already been made
    extend(subProto, SubC.prototype);
    SubC.prototype = subProto;
    SubC._super = SuperC.prototype;
}

function extend(target, source) {
    Object.getOwnPropertyNames(source)
        .forEach(function(property) {
            Object.defineProperty(target, property,
                Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(source, property));
        });
    return target;
}

Point.prototype.toString = function() {
    return "(" + this.x + "," + this.y + ")";
};

ColorPoint.prototype.toString = function() {
    return this.color + " " + Point.prototype.toString.call(this);
};

console.log(Point);
console.log(ColorPoint);

inherits(ColorPoint, Point);

console.log(ColorPoint.prototype); //Refers to the object from which all the instances are created from

console.log(ColorPoint.prototype.constructor); //The function itself

var greenPoint = new ColorPoint(1, 2, "Green");

console.log(greenPoint);

console.log(greenPoint.prototype); //Undefined. Objects have no prototype property

console.log(greenPoint.constructor); // greenPoint as an object has constructor, from which it is created i.e. function ColorPoint

console.log(greenPoint.constructor.prototype); //The constructor ColorPoint
```

I am not able to follow what inherits method is doing here. I understood pretty much how it is working using below strategy.

```
ColorPoint.prototype = Object.create(Point.prototype);//Point prototype is referenced to ColorPoints'
ColorPoint.prototype.constructor = ColorPoint;//Reset constructor
```

But I didn't understand why `subProto.constructor` is referring to `ColorPoint`. And next, why `extend` method parameters are not passed like ColorPoint, Point (child, parent) respectively.

Answer (score 0):

When you create an instance from a Constructor function using `new ColorPoint()` then the ColorPoint.prototype.constructor property is pointing to the Constructor function --> ColorPoint.

When you use `ColorPoint.prototype = Object.create` you override the constructor function with the Point constructor function, this is just setting it back to the correct function.

in the extend method all of the properties from the `source` object are being passed to the `target`.